# Assigning values to the relevant column sas macro

Tags: macros, sas

num...name...cost...ab...ac...ad...ae

1..........ac.......40
2..........ab.......10
3..........ae.......30
4..........ad.......20

Hi i'm very new in sas macro and i need help assigning cost values to the relevant column like this.

Could you please help me?

num...name...cost...ab...ac...ad...ae

1........ac.........40..........40
2........ab.........10....10
3........ae.........30  ........................30

4........ad.........20.................20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ab, ac, ad, ae... columns from your initial dataset.
And then have a look at proc transpose, it is exactly what you need: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1r2tjnp8ewe3sn1acnpnrs3xbad.htm

Answer (score 0):

A quick search through the SAS procedures leads to PROC TRANSPOSE
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#transpose-overview.htm

There are also numerous papers online detailing lots of examples of how to use PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
proc tranpose data=in out=out ;
  by num ;
  id name ;
  var cost ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

if for some reason you need it to be done via datastep, look into arrays rather then macros....

something like:

```
array _col(*) ab ac ad ae; 
  do i=1 to dim(_col); 
     if vname(_col)=name then _col(i)=cost; 
  end;
```

here is a good resource:
https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/97529_Using_Arrays_in_SAS_Programming.pdf

Comment: i think that was the solution i need. but i used proc transpose succesfully. i will keep in mind this. thank you very much